# Create variable from string/nameonly parameter to extract data in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to save the variable name and its contents easily from my script.

Currently :-

```
LOGFILE=/root/log.txt
TEST=/file/path
echo "TEST : ${TEST}" >> ${LOGFILE}
```

Desired :-

```
LOGFILE=/root/log.txt

function save()
{
    echo "$1 : $1" >> ${LOGFILE}
}

TEST=/file/path

save TEST
```

Obviously the above `save` function just saves `TEST : TEST`
Want I want it to save is `TEST : /file/path`

Can this be done? How? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use **Variable Indirection**.  Also, don't use the `function` keyword, it is not POSIX and also not necessary as long as you have `()` at the end of your function name.

```
LOGFILE=/root/log.txt

save()
{
    echo "$1 : ${!1}" >> ${LOGFILE}
}

TEST=/file/path

save TEST
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ TEST=foo; save(){ echo "$1 : ${!1}"; }; save TEST
TEST : foo
```

Comment: Wow, quick, precise, exactly what I want, and works perfectly. Many thanks.

Comment: Not Posix?  It's bash ... if you code for bash and you like to put "function" in from of your function name - you are free to do so.  It has its benefits ... if I always use the keyword I know I can do incremental search in a file to reach the next function (much clearer than looking for `()`) ... to each his own (again, if you are committed to `bash` as the tag here indicates).

Comment: .. Thanks BTW for the Variable Indirection hint ... I have gotten used to using `eval` but this is much cleaner

Comment: @nhed I prefer to use portable syntax wherever I can unless non-portable syntax brings me noticeable functional benefit. I'm a big advocate of `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` for the additional functionality but `function` makes you non-portable for no functional gain. I don't feel that searching for `function` is worth giving up portability because searching for `/\(\)/` gives pretty low false positives on functions.  But as you said, to each his own. Many people don't know `function` is not POSIX.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using *indirect expansion*:

```
echo "$1 : ${!1}"
```

Quoting from [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> The basic form of parameter expansion is ${parameter} [...] If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself. This is known as indirect expansion

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `printenv` function. It does exactly what it says on the tin, prints your environment. It can also take parameters

```
$ printenv
SSH_AGENT_PID=2068
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
...etc
```

You could do printenv and then grep for any vars you know you have defined and be done in two lines, such as:

```
$printenv | grep "VARNAME1\|VARNAME2"
VARNAME1=foo
VARNAME2=bar
```

Comment: I like using this **as well** as above, but it doesnt really answer my question, many thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped the gun when I saw that you were setting up environment variables as part of your question; didn't realize you truly were interested in building your own function.